# calculating resources for the jobs in accepted state

Tags: resources, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, estimation

I am new to hadoop and don't know whether it is possible or not to calculate the resources for the jobs which are in accepted state , if we can estimate the resource requirements , it will help in auto scaling the cluster as per resource requirements , and we can turn the jobs in accepted state to running , if it is possible can anyone give idea about how to start this or is there any resource calculator by default and how can i use it , can anyone share your valuable thoughts that help me.

I am able to get the jobs which are in accepted state and not able to calculate the resources , stuck here and don't know how to proceed further.